# Create parameterized primefaces components of different types

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my JSF webapp (using primefaces 5.0), I have multiple very similar input forms on different pages to edit entities which are being derivated from an abstract class called `DataContainer`:

```
public abstract class DataContainer<ValueType>{

   ValueType val; // Generic type for the value
   //...
}
```

*One* possible subclass would be:

```
public class IntegerContainer extends DataContainer<Integer>{
   public Type getType(){
     return Type.NUMBER; // Type is an enum to determine the type during runtime.
   }
   // ...
}
```

In the frontend, I'd like to use different PF components in order to edit different datatypes (thus, different subclasses of `DataContainer`): E.g. a `p:spinner` for numbers, `p:input` for text.

My current way to do this, is using the `rendered` attribute of the components, being true or false depending on the actual `Type` returned by `getType()` in comparison to my enums (`Type.*`):

```
<p:dataGrid ... var="entity">
   <p:spinner value="#{anyPM.intValue"} rendered="#{entity.type eq Type.NUMBER}" />
   <p:inputText  value="#{anyPM.stringValue}" rendered="#{entity.type eq Type.TEXT} />
</dataGrid>
```

Different pages are using different PM's - so any time i need to edit an entity of type `<? extends DataContainer>` i am writing down the same form just replacing the name of the PM.

Is there any way to dynamically generate the content of the dataGrid above (like including it as a template and setting the PM by parameter)?
Other suggestions to avoid nearly duplicated code in my xhtml's?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look at PrimeFaces Extensions DynaForm -> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/dynaForm.jsf